# How can I connect InfluxDB to DataGrid?

Tags: datagrid, influxdb, jetbrains-ide

I'm trying to connect my JetBrains DataGrid to InfluxDB.
But there is no InfluxDB in data sources:
[image]
Does anyone used DataGrid with InfluxDB?

Answer (score 2):

You can connect it if there is a **JDBC driver** for InfluxDB (if it exists, of course; right now it looks like there is no such driver).

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/2020.2/connecting-to-a-database.html#other

> If you connect to the vendor that is not in the list of supported data sources, DataGrip uses JDBC metadata for database object retrieval (introspection) and the Generic SQL dialect. The introspection with JDBC metadata means that some specific database objects will not appear in the database tree view. With the Generic SQL dialect, you will have basic code completion like `SELECT * FROM <table_name>`, but code completion will not include objects that were not retrieved during introspection.

---

Other than that: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-5158 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified with any progress.